# ClassNotFoundException OptionsStrategy

Tags: janusgraph

When i connect to remote server and try to modify a graph i get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/strategy/decoration/OptionsStrategy

I try search information about this exception. I think it happens because something conflict with version of janusgraph-core, gremlin-server and gremlin-driver

```
//pom file dependencies

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
//jgex-remote.properties file

gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=.../janus_connect_config.yaml
```

```
//janus_connect_config.yaml file

hosts: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
port: xxxx
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0,
  config: {
    ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry]
  }
}
```

```java
// java code
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input args must contains path to file with configuration");
        }

        String configFilePath = args[0];

        PropertiesConfiguration connectConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration(configFilePath);

        Cluster cluster = null;
        Client client = null;

        try {
            cluster = Cluster.open(connectConfig.getString("gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile"));
            client = cluster.connect();

            Bindings b = Bindings.instance();
            GraphTraversalSource graph = EmptyGraph.instance()
                    .traversal()
                    .withRemote(connectConfig);

            Vertex evnyh = graph.addV(b.of("label", "man"))
                    .property("name", "Evnyh")
                    .property("family", "Evnyhovich")
                    .next();
            Vertex lalka = graph.addV(b.of("label", "man"))
                    .property("name", "Lalka")
                    .property("family", "Lalkovich")
                    .next();

            graph.V(b.of("outV", evnyh)).as("a")
                    .V(b.of("inV", lalka)).as("b")
                    .addE(b.of("label", "friend")).from("a")
                    .next();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // nothing to do, just close client
                }
            }

            if (cluster != null) {
                try {
                    cluster.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // nothing to do, just close cluster
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a version mismatch. Note that JanusGraph 0.3.1 is bound to the TinkerPop 3.3.x line of code:

https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.3.1/pom.xml#L72

and `OptionStrategy` (and [related functionality](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2053)) was not added in TinkerPop until the 3.4.x line of code. JanusGraph therefore cannot process requests which use that sort of functionality.

Comment: its "very" informatively... what to do with it now?

Comment: either downgrade to your tinkerpop dependencies to 3.3.x (preferrebly the explicit version janus graph uses in 3.3.3 OR do your own build of the master branch which seems to be on 3.4.x now OR wait for release of JanusGraph 0.4.0 https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-dev/myWnQEhNTPk/V39wZaIvBwAJ